# Aurora Serverless AWS strong read consistency?

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Is it possible to get strong read consistency (read-after-write) with Aurora Serverless? I'm using the data api client.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 falvors of Aurora Serverless:

1. v1 (~2019) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html
2. v2 (2022) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html

This question was asked when Serverless v1 was accounced.

Aurora Serverless v1 will always give you read-after-write consistency. It is pretty much a single (writer) instance Aurora provisioned cluster with serverless support to automatically scale (up or down) the compute.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html

However, Aurora Serverless v2 is very similar to regular Aurora. v2 essentially gives you an new instance type called "db.serverless" which scales in-place, instantaneously. You can add N db.serverless instances into a cluster, and each of them would act like a self-scaling capacity (read replica). Hence, you get the same level of consistency guarantees as regular Aurora, where ONLY THE WRITER gives you read-after-write consistency. Reader nodes and reader serverless capacity will continue to be eventually consistent.

Hope this clarifies things!

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. Writer node replicates to readers asynchronously with non-zero latency. A request to read within that latency window will produce a result inconsistent with the state on the writer node. Docs declare latency within region of 10s of milliseconds, and under a second cross-region. You can get strong consistency when the cluster has only one instance, and therefore nothing to be inconsistent with :p https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-poc.html

Comment: This question was asked about Aurora Serverless v1 (which is different from the new 2022 Aurora Serverless feature). Aurrora Serverless v1 does NOT have read replicas - you configure a min and max capacity, and they internally translate to a certain instance type. When your cluster automatically scales up, behind the scenes, you are swapping to a larger instance type. The node is always a "writer" and hence it is always strongly consistent. Doc: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v1.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.architecture

Comment: For the 2022 Aurora Serverless v2, yes, you can have dedicated "autoscaling" instances for writer and reader. In that scenario, you can only have strong consistency on the writer instance.

Comment: I agree with that all! The only problem is that in 2023 you have an answer that says "Aurora Serverless will always give you read-after-write consistency." Update your answer with nuance from your comments, and describe the case when aurora does NOT have strong consistency (literally anytime a cluster has > 1 instances) and I'd happily upvote!

Comment: @lance.dolan - I've updated the answer. Pls review and vote if it makes sense now. Open to suggestions as well.

Comment: @niqui LMK if the updated answer addresses your Q. Feel free to accept.